# Nginx can not read .php routes of laravel who not exist

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have created some Laravel routes with they have ".php" extention, such as

```
Route::get('/api/send.php', function(){
    echo 'Hi There';
});
```

But when I open the route it shows 404 error in Nginx server... That is Nginx configurations

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

What is the problem? I have used the same code it worked before..

Thanks

**SOLVED**

It solved by changing

```
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
```

in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf to

```
try_files $fastcgi_script_name /index.php?$query_string;
```

Comment: I Just tried that code and i get the page with that message "Hi There". Something is wrong with your settings

Comment: I am using ubuntu server 18, I don't know do you think what should I check?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common problem with nginx configured to serve PHP applications, especially Laravel. You can reproduce it on sites like laravel.com, e.g: [`laravel.com/example.php`](https://laravel.com/example.php).

The default configuration (what you're probably using in `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`) is this:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

And [`fastcgi_script_name` is](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#variables)...

> request URI or, if a URI ends with a slash, request URI with an index file name configured by the fastcgi_index directive appended to it. This variable can be used to set the SCRIPT_FILENAME and PATH_TRANSLATED parameters that determine the script name in PHP. For example, for the “/info/” request with the following directives

That means, when a request URI contains `.php` it is treated as if it is a request for a PHP file, and if that PHP file doesn't exist an error is returned by nginx -- it never reaches your application.

The solution is to force `fastcgi_script_name` to always equal your application's entry point, in this case that's `index.php`. You can either edit `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` or add it into your location block like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
}
```

Your application will now receive every request, including those that have `.php` in the path.

Comment: Solved by changing replacing `try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;` to `try_files $fastcgi_script_name /index.php?$query_string;`